# React app no longer loading with <ltng> component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, static-resources, lightning-community, react

As SF support for third party frameworks in communities was poor we decided to implement it using the  component like so

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.react_app  + '/www/js/main.js'}"   
              beforeLoadingResources="{!c.preReact}"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.startReact}" />
```

Which renders the app into a div with the id of "app", this worked perfectly until the summer 18 update and now all of our sandboxes have this error:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'parseInt' of object '[object Object]'

It comes from "aura_prod.js:852" having an issue with the script.
This ran fine unchanged before the summer 18 update and runs perfectly locally and on non sf environments.

What could be causing this error? How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to use the <lightning:container>? I think that is the recommended way when dealing with external third party libs like react

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_container.htm

Comment: That was our initial approach but  <lightning:container> does not work in communities surprisingly!

Comment: what a bummer - have you checked if the same critical updates are enabled/disabled in you pre-release org as in your prod org? Especially the locker service enhancement for stricter CSP? Maybe that is causing the issue

Comment: I am unfamiliar with some of those terms, have there been changes to locker settings in the update I need to change?

Comment: Just make sure that you have the same critical updates activated/deactivated in your Summer 18 Org and the other org where the container is still working - go to Setup and search for Critical Updates.
More information about the enhanced security of LockerService: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_lc_locker_service.htm

Comment: Oh we don't have a working container/community anymore, it looks like all were forced to update to summer18?

Comment: I'm experience this error while loading one of the plugins (Freedraw) after loading Leaflet.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else with the same issue, for us it seemed to be that in the summer18 update some polyfills were added for their code and then ones for our code were conflicting, In particular parseInt prototype on Number.

So far the solution seems to be related to webpack, don't use "babel-polyfill", instead use "transform-runtime".

> If you are looking for something that won't modify globals to be used in a tool/library, checkout the transform-runtime plugin.

[transform-runtime docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: I'm trying to use Leaflet.FreeDraw (https://github.com/Wildhoney/Leaflet.FreeDraw) library for making a free hand drawing on a Map. I'm facing the same error when the version of the component is >40.0. (i.e. LockerService on). Where do you suggest I make a change in the library?